# How do I fix this Smart Folder problem? It keeps switching off of "This Mac"

Tags: finder, smart-folders

I created a Smart Folder in the finder called "TV" which searches for files of type movie created in the last 7 days. When I created the search in the first place, I clicked on "Search This Mac" to find all files anywhere. But now, even when I have new files that I've downloaded nothing will show up in the folder. When I click on Search criteria on the top it will say

Search: This Mac   TV

and TV will be selected. But, remember, I saved it as "This Mac"

Why won't it stick to "This Mac"? Why does it keep going to "TV" which doesn't make sense anyway, if there's nothing in a folder, then it can't find files in that folder of the type that it's supposed to be searching for...

Answer (score 2):

Here's the steps I used to do what you're looking for which seem to be working the way you want.

Open Finder and click File > New Smart Folder - or press <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>

Then setup as I have in the screenshot below and click 'Save' near the top right.

[image: Smart Folder Settings]

Then, when the little drop-down menu appears for you to save, select the options like I have below.

[image: Save Dialog]

Now, you'll get a window left behind like this.

[image: Smart Folder]

Now, close your new Smart Folder.  Then in Finder, open a normal finder window with either File > New Finder Window or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>

Your 'TV' Smart Folder will be listed under the 'Search For' section on the bottom-left if you expand it out, like so

[image: Finder Window]

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put into this answer. Unfortunately, that's exactly what I've done. It works just as you've shown here, the first time... but then if I close that folder and come back to it, say in a couple of days, it somehow has snapped back to not searching "This Mac". And actually, I just tried it again, and this one is working, but I clicked on "Search Criteria" and it still is clicked on the name of the smart folder and not this mac. I'm using 10.6.6

Comment: Bummer!  Have you tried going to `youruserfolder/Library/Saved Searches` and deleting TV then recreating it?  Maybe something weird happened during your creation...

Comment: Hey, looks like it is a bug.  See here: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa;jsessionid=318846CEC95DB4DA8E1F61EC0622B106.node0?messageID=12210278&#12210278

Comment: ...and here:  http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=11221507

Comment: ...and how somebody figured out the bug: http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=10292658#10292658

Answer (score 0):

Does it ask you to save when you click on "This Mac" and then switch away to, say, another search? I just tried it out, it should ask you to save.

Are you on 10.5 or 10.6?

Cheers.